# How to make IntVar and StringVar display in the same widget?

Tags: python, tkinter, label

So, I am trying make a label that displays both StringVar and an IntVar, though when I try to put them in, like so...

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()
parent = ttk.Frame(root)
parent.grid()

string = StringVar()
integer = IntVar()

string.set("Blah =")
integer.set(10)

both = str((string.get(), str(integer.get())))
print(both)

both = StringVar()
both.set((string.get(), str(integer.get())))
print(both.get())

label = ttk.Label(parent, textvariable=(both))
label.grid()

root.mainloop()
```

Now, this is the closest I was able to get, because the other ways didn't even display the textvariables in the widget.
For some reason the code when printed returns: ('Blah =', '10').
Like a list that has been printed. But the label displays: {Blah =} 10

Can someone please tell me why it displays with these instead of just displaying the variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for how to format a string.

```
both = StringVar()
both.set( "{}{}".format( string.get(), integer.get() ) )
```

Comment: So, @cricket_007, does the curly brackets basically say there are 2 variables, place variable one here, and variable two here. Then sets it so the variables display in the format you created with the curly brackets?